Avoiding even powers in partial fraction decomposition
Consider the expression:
$$\frac{1}{(x-a_1)^{n_1} (x-a_2)^{{n_2}}}$$
where $a_1$ and $a_2$ are real numbers and $n_1 \geq 2$ and $n_2 \geq 1$
Am I correct that it is impossible to decompose this in a way where all the partial fractions are of the form $\frac{1}{(x-k)^n}$ with $n$ being odd?
For example,
$$\frac{1}{(x-1)^3
   (x-2)}=\frac{1}{-2+x}-\frac{1}{(-1+x)^3}-\frac{1}{(-1+x)^2}-\frac{1}{-1+x}$$
Here I do not see a way to avoid the fraction involving the even power: $\frac{1}{(-1+x)^2}$
Thanks

Welcome to MSE. For some basic information about writing mathematics at this site see, e.g., basic help on mathjax notation, mathjax tutorial and quick reference, main meta site math tutorial and equation editing how-to.
